# CGRectContainsPoint point not registering despite being inside frame

Tags: ios, swift, frame, cgrect, touchesbegan

I am putting together a custom keyboard for some practise in Swift. The buttons on the keyboard will all have a greater touch area than the button frame itself. For this I have added a variable of type **CGRect** named **touchFrame** to my custom button class. I will manually set the **touchFrame** variable for all my instances. I am then using **CGRectContainsPoint** inside **touchesBegan** to determine if any of the **touchFrame** rectangles have been touched.

Here I have given a value to the button instances' touchFrame variable:

```
      button01.touchFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 32.0, 59.0)
      button02.touchFrame = CGRectMake(32.0, 0.0, 32.0, 59.0)
      button03.touchFrame = CGRectMake(64.0, 0.0, 32.0, 59.0)
```

Here is the touchesBegan code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        var touchPoint: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

        characterButtonArray = [button01, button02, button03]

        for button: CharacterButton in characterButtonArray {

            if CGRectContainsPoint(button.touchFrame, touchPoint.locationInView(self.view))   {

                characterButtonTouchInside(button)

            }
        }   
    }
```

In the following image the red lines show the area of the **touchFrame** rectangles, this is the area which should fire the **characterButtonTouchInside(button)** as seen in the code above, but instead, the function only fires when you touch inside the buttons' frame (the white buttons in the image below).

[image]

I have no clue as to why this would happen. Could the fact that the **keyboardViewController** is a subclass of **UIInputViewController** have any effect?

Any help would be much, much appreciated.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint, or `println` and get the values of `touchFrame` and `touchPoint.locationInView(self.view)` so that they can be manually compared?

Comment: @MikeS I can print the value of both touchFrame and touchPoint.locationInView(self.view) and the rect does indeed contain the point, however again, all this is only when my touch is inside the white button frame. If the touch is outside the white button, but inside the touchFrame the if statement never fires.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I misread that part before. Your `touchesBegan` is defined in `keyboardViewController`, right?

Comment: I am assuming that I am testing against a point inside **view** by writing touchPoint.locationInView(self.view), which makes it even more odd that touches are only registered inside the buttons.

Comment: @MikeS yup it's inside the keyboardViewController class.

Comment: Oh, it looks like `UIInputViewController` uses `inputView` and not `view` for its child views. Maybe try: `touchPoint.locationInView(self.inputView)`.

Comment: @MikeS tried self.inputView but sadly it didn't work. I have used self.view in other places with no problems. But I can see how it would make more sense that it's self.inputView. No luck though.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you have user interaction disabled for the "outer" view of your button, but enabled for the actual buttony bit of it. Where *is* your touchesBegan?

Comment: @MattGibson actually the interaction is disabled for the buttons and enabled for the outside view. And my touchesBegan is inside my KeyboardViewcontroller

Comment: For now I have added a UIButton on top of the UIView yet below all the other buttons. It works, but this is sort of a workaround.